# Pattern matching when using first two values of list

Tags: haskell

I am having an issue with pattern matching when using the two first values of a list.

```
foo [] = []
foo (x:y:ys) = foo ys
```

This works fine when the original list in the argument is a multiple of 2, but not otherwise.  I get an error stating "Non-exhaustive patterns in function foo"

I am wondering how to match the pattern when there is no y value in the x:y:ys. (What would the pattern look like in this case?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
foo [x] = ...
```

and

```
foo (x:[]) =
```

both match a list with just one element.